# How to specify a prefix when uploading to S3 using activestorage's direct upload?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-5.2

With a standard S3 configuration:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID:        [AWS ID]
AWS_BUCKET:               [bucket name]
AWS_REGION:               [region]
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY:    [secret]
```

I can upload a file to S3 (using direct upload) with this Rails 5.2 code (only relevant code shown):

`form.file_field :my_asset, direct_upload: true`

This will effectively put my asset in the root of my S3 bucket, upon submitting the form.

How can I specify a prefix (e.g. "development/", so that I can mimic a folder on S3)?

Comment: Not sure if that's currently possible - have a look at the source code here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activestorage/lib/active_storage/service/s3_service.rb#L19

Answer (score 21, accepted):

2022 update: as of Rails 6.1 (check [this commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/4dba136c83cc808282625c0d5b195ce5e0bbaa68)), this is actually supported:

```rb
user.avatar.attach(key: "avatars/#{user.id}.jpg", io: io, content_type: "image/jpeg", filename: "avatar.jpg")
```

Comment: This one should be the right/best answer.

Comment: How can this be used when has_many_attached macro is set?

Comment: It may be possible to do at the model layer as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75304623/457850

Answer (score 11):

My current workaround (at least until ActiveStorage introduces the option to pass a path for the `has_one_attached` and `has_many_attached` macros) on S3 is to implement the [move_to method](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/S3/Object.html#move_to-instance_method).

So I'm letting ActiveStorage save the image to S3 as it normally does right now (at the top of the bucket), then moving the file into a folder structure.

The `move_to` method basically copies the file into the folder structure you pass then deletes the file that was put at the root of the bucket. This way your file ends up where you want it.

So for instance if we were storing driver details: `name` and `drivers_license`, save them as you're already doing it so that it's at the top of the bucket.

Then implement the following (I put mine in a helper):

```
        module DriversHelper

          def restructure_attachment(driver_object, new_structure)

          old_key = driver_object.image.key

          begin
            # Passing S3 Configs
            config = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join('config', 'storage.yml'))

            s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: config['amazon']['region'],
                                       credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(config['amazon']['access_key_id'], config['amazon']['secret_access_key']))

            # Fetching the licence's Aws::S3::Object
            old_obj = s3.bucket(config['amazon']['bucket']).object(old_key)

            # Moving the license into the new folder structure
            old_obj.move_to(bucket: config['amazon']['bucket'], key: "#{new_structure}")


            update_blob_key(driver_object, new_structure)
          rescue => ex
            driver_helper_logger.error("Error restructuring license belonging to driver with id #{driver_object.id}: #{ex.full_message}")
          end
          end

          private

          # The new structure becomes the new ActiveStorage Blob key
          def update_blob_key(driver_object, new_key)
            blob = driver_object.image_attachment.blob
            begin
              blob.key = new_key
              blob.save!
            rescue => ex
              driver_helper_logger.error("Error reassigning the new key to the blob object of the driver with id #{driver_object.id}: #{ex.full_message}")
            end
          end

          def driver_helper_logger
            @driver_helper_logger ||= Logger.new("#{Rails.root}/log/driver_helper.log")
          end
        end
```

It's important to update the blob key so that references to the key don't return errors.

If the key is not updated any function attempting to reference the image will look for it in it's former location (at the top of the bucket) rather than in it's new location.

I'm calling this function from my controller as soon as the file is saved (that is, in the create action) so that it looks seamless even though it isn't.

While this may not be the best way, it works for now.

FYI: Based on the example you gave, the `new_structure` variable would be `new_structure = "development/#{driver_object.image.key}"`.

I hope this helps! :)

Comment: It's a shame work-arounds like these are needed for actions like this. This is also needed to change the acl permissions and storage type.

Comment: Check my answer below, this is supported as of Rails 6.1

Answer (score 4):

Thank you, Sonia, for your answer.

I tried your solution and it works great, but I encountered problems with overwriting attachments. I often got **IntegrityError** while doing it. I think, that this and *checksum* handling may be the reason why the Rails core team don't want to add passing pathname feature. It would require changing the entire logic of the **upload** method.

**ActiveStorage::Attached#create_from_blob** method, could also accepts an **ActiveStorage::Blob** object. So I tried a different approach:

1. Create a **Blob** manually with a key that represents desired file structure and uploaded attachment.
2. Attach created **Blob** with the ActiveStorage method.

In my usage, the solution was something like that:

```
def attach file # method for attaching in the model
  blob_key = destination_pathname(file)
  blob = ActiveStorage::Blob.find_by(key: blob_key.to_s)

  unless blob
    blob = ActiveStorage::Blob.new.tap do |blob|
      blob.filename = blob_key.basename.to_s
      blob.key = blob_key
      blob.upload file
      blob.save!
    end
  end

  # Attach method from ActiveStorage
  self.file.attach blob
end
```

Thanks to passing a full pathname to **Blob**'s key I received desired file structure on a server.

Comment: Why is this not working for me. Where would I put self.file.attach blob? in the model ? How should I invoke it?

Comment: Not working for me either. Updates blob key on 'save' back to some md5. If you force it again, it changes the '/'es in the path to '-'s and throws FileNotFound if called upon

Comment: Check my answer above, this is supported as of Rails 6.1

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, that’s not currently possible. I’d suggest creating a bucket for Active Storage to use exclusively.

Comment: I believe there are [no plans to add this](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/32790) and we would need to implement something like Sonia's answer below if we require this functionality.

Comment: Oh... you again.  That's just not a viable option, @George Claghorn .  So, so many people want this, I don't understand why you're just nixing an option that literally every competing library has always had the ability to do.

Comment: Same as @mpowered... I just can't understand why you wouldn't want to add that feature. At least give us a reason, not just say "no". Even Carrierwave makes it easy to do it.

Comment: @George FYI. Keypaths are ***critical*** to storage management in s3, unrelated to application logic. If you, hey/basecamp, are dumping your uploads to bucket root, i can promise you, lots of pain and $$$$$ coming your way.

Answer (score 0):

The above solution will still give **IntegrityError**, need to use File.open(file). Thank Though for idea.

```
class History < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :gs_history_file

  def attach(file) # method for attaching in the model
    blob_key = destination_pathname(file)
    blob = ActiveStorage::Blob.find_by(key: blob_key.to_s)
    unless blob
      blob = ActiveStorage::Blob.new.tap do |blob|
        blob.filename = blob_key.to_s
        blob.key = blob_key
        #blob.byte_size = 123123
        #blob.checksum = Time.new.strftime("%Y%m%d-") + Faker::Alphanumeric.alpha(6)
        blob.upload File.open(file)
        blob.save!
      end
    end

    # Attach method from ActiveStorage
    self.gs_history_file.attach blob
  end

  def destination_pathname(file)
    "testing/filename-#{Time.now}.xlsx"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind monkey patching... It's as easy as this:

```rb
Rails.configuration.to_prepare do
  ActiveStorage::Blob.class_eval do
    # Monkey patch key property with prefix.
    def key
      self[:key] ||= "my_custom_prefix/#{self.class.generate_unique_secure_token(length: self.class::MINIMUM_TOKEN_LENGTH)}"
    end
  end
end
```

The method this overwrites is here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/fc7befc87af05796612d03531b21c691699aeb74/activestorage/app/models/active_storage/blob.rb#L187

The `key` column is what's used for uploading, fetching, and all other methods. So things continue to work as expected. Also, since the method checks for whether the `key` is already present before assignment, it shouldn't break prior uploads.